# Base 64 decode and parse string in shell script/Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

I have input csv file like this and i want to base64 decode the string for clientid column.After decoding i want to parse the data and place the data in following format in output

```
ip,clientid,device
3.3.3.3,W3sNCiAgIm5hbWUiIDogImpzb24taWQiLA0KICAidmFsdWUiIDogIjEyMyINCn0sIHsNCiAgIm5hbWUiIDogIm5hbWUtaWQiLA0KICAidmFsdWUiIDogIjY3OCINCn0gXQ==,iPhone
7.7.7.7,W3sNCiAgIm5hbWUiIDogImpzb24taWQiLA0KICAidmFsdWUiIDogIjEyMyINCn0sIHsNCiAgIm5hbWUiIDogIm5hbWUtaWQiLA0KICAidmFsdWUiIDogIjY3OCINCn0gXQ==,Samsung
```

Output i want in csv is

```
ip,clientid,device
3.3.3.3,json-id||123##name-id||678,iPhone
7.7.7.7,json-id||657##name-id||234,Samsung
```

I want to do it using shell script alone .Something like this to extract the data.But not sure how I can parse the data in shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '{printf "%s", $1","substr($2,1,9999)","substr($3,1,15)}' input.csv >output.csv
echo "W3sNCiAgIm5hbWUiIDogImpzb24taWQiLA0KICAidmFsdWUiIDogIjEyMyINCn0sIHsNCiAgIm5hbWUiIDogIm5hbWUtaWQiLA0KICAidmFsdWUiIDogIjY3OCINCn0gXQ==" | base64 --decode
```

Another option is I can work on the output.csv and write a python script to get the data of clientid column and then parse and rewrite to file.
If possible ,can we also ensure that while parsing the "name" key should have name_id or json_id then only we parse the values out of those?

Can someone please suggest

Comment: Your example is a bit confusing, because the content on your example "output I want" doesn't look anything like the base64-decoded strings you get from your sample input.  In any case, writing a Python script would probably be the easiest solution. Python has modules both for parsing CSV files (`csv`) and for decoding base64 content (`base64`).

Comment: ok thanks.I also thought python is the way to go .I was just thinking if shell script can also handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `base64` to decode the encoded string along with `json` to parse the decoded string.

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import base64
import json

s = StringIO("""ip,clientid,device
3.3.3.3,W3sNCiAgIm5hbWUiIDogImpzb24taWQiLA0KICAidmFsdWUiIDogIjEyMyINCn0sIHsNCiAgIm5hbWUiIDogIm5hbWUtaWQiLA0KICAidmFsdWUiIDogIjY3OCINCn0gXQ==,iPhone
7.7.7.7,W3sNCiAgIm5hbWUiIDogImpzb24taWQiLA0KICAidmFsdWUiIDogIjEyMyINCn0sIHsNCiAgIm5hbWUiIDogIm5hbWUtaWQiLA0KICAidmFsdWUiIDogIjY3OCINCn0gXQ==,Samsung""")

# read the csv string
df = pd.read_csv(s)


def parse(s):
    p = json.loads(base64.b64decode(s).decode())
    
    json_id_value = None
    name_id_value = None
    
    for i in p:
        if(i['name'] == 'json-id'):
            json_id_value = i['value']
        if(i['name'] == 'name-id'):
            name_id_value = i['value']
            
    return 'json-id' + '||' + str(json_id_value) + '##' + 'name-id' + '||'+ str(name_id_value)

df['clientid'] = df['clientid'].apply(lambda x: parse(x))

print(df)
```

```
        ip                    clientid   device
0  3.3.3.3  json-id||123##name-id||678   iPhone
1  7.7.7.7  json-id||123##name-id||678  Samsung
```

Finally, if you want to save

```
df.to_csv('my_csv.csv')
```

Comment: Can we check the name key and add to dataframe. Like if the decoded json string has only "name" : "json-id"  or  "name" : "name-id" then only we take the corresponding value?

Comment: @pythonNinja are you not sure whether the keys will exist or not?

Comment: yes the example i gave is a generic one.So in real i will have a bunch of these elements in the array which i decode .I need to iterate on that array and find if the  "name" key has : "json-id" or  "name-id"

Comment: @pythonNinja check the answer

Comment: cant we directly pull from the input csv .Do we need to have StringIO conversion?

Comment: yes, obviously `df = pd.read_csv(you_csv_file.csv)`

Comment: For showing example i did this, not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
while IFS=, read -r ip clientid device; do
    if (( nr++ )); then
        clientid=$(base64 -d <<< "$clientid" | jq -r '.[] | "\(.name)||\(.value)"' | awk 'ORS="##"' | sed 's/##$//')
    fi
    echo "$ip,$clientid,$device"
done < file.csv
```

Output:

```
ip,clientid,device
3.3.3.3,json-id||123##name-id||678,iPhone
7.7.7.7,json-id||123##name-id||678,Samsung
```

Comment: Can we also check the name key and add to clientid varaible. Like if the decoded json string has only "name" : "json-id" or "name" : "name-id" then only we take the corresponding value?

Comment: Yes. If the json string contains either "json-id" or "name-id" only, the
initial value of `clientid` variable contains "as-is". We can parse the
variable then add the missing or desired value if it is determined.
If you can provide an example input and desired output, I am ready to
update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @tshino.I think i will go by the python script way.I am seeing some concerns here with parsing timings as i have more than 150 columns in CSV in actual